# How in tailwindcss to implement data listing with badges

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I in tailwindcss to implement data listing with badges, like I did in bootstrap :

```
<ul class="list-group m-0 p-1">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        Number of ads
        <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
            <span id="span_adsCount" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        Active ads
        <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
            <span id="span_activeAdsCount" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please, link to example...

Thanks!

Comment: Here, it comes down to CSS so there is no answer on how to make it in tailwindcss. You could pretty much mirror the styling but it depends on how you want it to look like. Bootstrap and Tailwind are not like `fetch` and `axios` transposable tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [Tailwind Play working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/OLqnHni59c).

Nonetheless, I highly recommend to go through the [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/). They are quite self explanatory.

```
<ul class="w-48 divide-y-2 divide-gray-200">
  <li class="flex justify-between items-center space-x-2 py-2 px-4 bg-gray-100 whitespace-nowrap rounded">
    <div>
      Number of ads
    </div>
    <div class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-blue-600 flex justify-center items-center text-blue-50">
      2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex justify-between items-center space-x-2 py-2 px-4 bg-gray-100 whitespace-nowrap rounded">
    <div>
      Active ads
    </div>
    <div class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-blue-600 flex justify-center items-center text-blue-50">
      4
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="flex justify-between items-center space-x-2 py-2 px-4 bg-gray-100 whitespace-nowrap rounded">
    <div>
      Expired ads
    </div>
    <div class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-blue-600 flex justify-center items-center text-blue-50">
      1
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```